# Bluetooth connectivity in windows mobile 6.5

Tags: windows, windows-mobile-6.5

How to set up the environment windows mobile 6.5,my system is running windows 7.
I want to develop the bluetooth application in windows phone.Could you please provide me the information of bluetooth api& Socket api in any version like 6.0 or 6.5.My device is sony ericsson xperia x1 [WM6.5] to check the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first point, install Visual studio 2008 (not 2010!).

Then install Windows Mobile SDK:

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=6135

Optionally install emulator and other samples:

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17284

Follow this instructions :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb158496.aspx

Then take a look at this samples:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb158754.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb158664.aspx

Here are lot of useful links:

http://www.wiimoteproject.com/bluetooth-and-connectivity-knowledge-center/bluetooth-sdk%27s-and-coding-with-bluetooth-support-documentation/